# Составной ключ в Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net

Допустим, есть класс, у которого есть 2 цифровых поля.

Хотелось бы эти 2 поля сделать первичным ключем в Dictionary.

В будущем этот ключ будет использоваться для поиска совпавших значений между 2 мя словарями.

Как это можно сделать, что бы не потерять в производительности?

У меня была идея, хранить их как строку, но может быть есть решение лучше?

**P.S**

Dictionary использую из-за высокой скорости поиска по ключу.

К моему удивлению, DataTable оказался тормознутее=( на 20к строк

Comment: А что за числа? Двузначные, трехзначные или вообще любые могут быть?

Comment: Насчет производительности не уверен, но можно попробовать Dictionary<Tuple<T1,T2>, T3>

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk, а разве тогда он не будет проверять равенство ссылок? Мне нужно именно сами значения сверять, а не равество ссылок.

Comment: @Michael любые.

Comment: @iluxa1810 да, действительно Tuple это класс, но я только что проверил и выяснил, что при добавлении он смотрит на элементы Tuple. т.е. при попытке второй раз добавить `d.Add(new Tuple(1, 1), 1);` выдало ошибку `элемент с таким ключом уже существует`.

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk, это потому что у Tuple переопределены методы GetHashCode и Equals

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk, кажется, он структура.

Comment: @Qwertiy, [класс](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx): `public class Tuple<T1, T2> : IStructuralEquatable, IStructuralComparable, 
 IComparable`

Comment: @Grundy, да, с KeyValuePair перепутал.

Comment: @iluxa1810: Если будете использовать самописную структуру для ключа, не забывайте, что для неё стоит переопределить `Equals` и определить `IEquatable<Self>`/`IComparable<Self>`, иначе сравнение по умолчанию может использовать медленную рефлексию.

Comment: @iluxa1810: Вот здесь есть немного по теме: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454619/10105

Comment: @VladD, жесть, не знал, что структуры при сравнении могут рефлексию использовать

Comment: @Grundy ну а как еще гарантировать корректную реализацию при наличии ссылочных полей?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Как один из вариантов

- Можно использовать класс [Tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx). Например `Dictionary<Tuple<T1,T2>, T3>`,
  где T1, T2, T3 значения любых типов. В `Tuple` сравниваться будет по
  внутренним значениям.

  > у Tuple переопределены методы GetHashCode и Equals    © Grundy
- Использовать структуру, т.к. у структур идет сравнение по всем имеющимся полям
- [Передавать `IEqualityComparer<T>` в конструктор](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms132072(v=vs.110).aspx), где Т - тип ключа. Сравнение будет производиться с использованием компаратора.

Answer (score 11):

Есть несколько путей использовать *составной* ключ для [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) (аналогично для HashSet)

1. Использовать структуру. Правила сравнения структур таковы, что сравниваются значения всех полей, а не ссылки на объекты.
2. Использовать класс с переопределенными методами `Equals`, `GetHashCode`. Это позволит использовать для вычисления хэша не все поля класса, а только нужные.
3. Использовать класс реализующий [IEquatable<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx)
4. Использовать при создании словаря перегрузку конструктора принимающую [IEqualityComparer<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms132073(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Привношу пример кода из [дублирующего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/686596/dictionary-and-custom-pair).

Классу `Dictionary` для того, чтобы обращаться к элементу по ключу, надо сравнивать ключи друг с другом.

Поэтому необходимо реализовать операцию сравнения двух объектов составного ключа, например, реализовав интерфейс `IEquatable<ComplexKey>` и переопределив метод `object.Equals` и `object.GetHashCode`.

Пример реализации IEquatable и переопределения `Equals` и `GetHashCode`:

```
public class ComplexKey : IEquatable<ComplexKey>
{
    private int value1;
    private string value2;

    public ComplexKey(int value1, string value2)
    {
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

    public bool Equals(ComplexKey other)
    {
        return EqualityComparer<int>.Default.Equals(value1, other.value1)
            && EqualityComparer<string>.Default.Equals(value2, other.value2);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        if (other is ComplexKey)
            return Equals((ComplexKey)other);

        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        var result = 17;
        unckecked
        {
            result = 31 * result + EqualityComparer<int>.Default.GetHashCode(value1);
            result = 31 * result + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(value2);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Методы `Equal` просто сравнивают попарно все значения составного ключа и возвращают `true` только тогда, когда все поля класса совпадают.

Метод `GetHashCode` считает значение хеша способом, который на SO [набрал больше всего плюсов](https://stackoverflow.com/a/113600/1051621).

Comment: Текст тоже стоит перенести, хотя бы частично, чтобы описать, что именно происходит в коде

Comment: Замечание: если один составной ключ вкладывается в другой - они должны использовать разные константы для вычисления хеша.

Answer (score 3):

Вероятно, [`Tuple`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx) подойдёт для использования в качестве ключа.

Comment: А Dictionary разве не будет игнорировать, что находится в Truple и следить за уникальностью ссылок?

Comment: @iluxa1810, вроде нет, проверь.