# Получить данные ключа из Dictionary<object, string>

Tags: c#

Уже сомневаюсь, правильно ли начал делать, поэтому хочется разумного разъяснения.
Предварительно заполняю БД, где создаю словарь, хранящий объект пользователя как ключ, и значением является пароль его учётки:

```
Dictionary<User, string> instructors = new Dictionary<User, string>();
instructors.Add(new Instructor { UserName = "norbertwiener@science.ru", Email = "norbertwiener@science.ru", Name = "Norbert", Surname = "Wiener" }, "wiener");
```

Сейчас мне необходимо заполнить другую таблицу, где нужно сослаться на конкретного преподавателя, и как мне можно получить `Surname`, к примеру, пятого пользователя из словаря?

Comment: вообще словарь не гарантирует порядок элементов, но можно воспользоваться методами Linq: `Skip` и `First`

Comment: @Grundy, не, мне не порядок важен, а как обратиться к ключу так, чтобы получить из него данные от `Instructor`

Comment: instructors.First(o => o.Key.UserName == "norbertwiener@science.ru").Value - получите пароль

Comment: Мне кажется ты неверно используешь словарь. Если у тебя уже есть Instructor - то значение свойства ты можешь получить напрямую из этого объекта, не за чем лезть в словарь. К тому же, если у тебя User не реализует свои Equals и GetHashCode - то даже смысла использовать объекты этого класса в качестве ключа словаря - нет

Comment: @Grundy, просто у меня же несколько инструкторов, а мне надо назначить в другой таблице конкретного)

Comment: [связанный вопрос про составной ключ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/619605/186999)

Comment: @guitarhero, в любом случае в качестве ключа проще использовать какое-нибудь уникальное поле типа UserName, вместо целого объекта

Comment: @Grundy, вот я и хотел узнать, разумно ли вообще такую логику выстраивать)

Comment: @guitarhero, честно говоря не особо логику увидел :)

Comment: А что мешает в объекте `User` объявить свойство Password?

Comment: @adamshakhabov, в объекте и так есть хэш пароля. не очень разумно, на мой взгляд, хранить там пароль и хэш