# Dictionary and custom pair

Tags: c#

```
public class Pair<FT, ST>
{
    public FT x;
    public ST y;
    public Pair()
    { }
    public Pair(FT a, ST b)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
}
Dictionary<Pair<int, int>,int> used = new Dictionary<Pair<int, int>, int>();
```

Есть код выше. Я добавляю в used данные таким образом

```
used[new Pair<int, int>(x, y)] = 1;
```

И когда хочу проверить `used.ContainsKey(new Pair<int, int>(x, y))`, то всегда выдается false, даже тогда, когда такие же x,y уже есть. Просто добавляются еще раз. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Замените class на struct. Классы по умолчанию сравниваются по ссылке, структуры - по значению. Таким образом, вы каждый раз создаете новый экземпляр, которого не было до этого в словаре.

Comment: @Vlad причем тут struct? У него не хватает перегрузки Equals

Comment: @PavelMayorov, это один из вариантов решения. Для структуры не нужно будет писать перегрузку Equals. Мне кажется, что в данном случае лучше подходит этот вариант.

Comment: @Vlad это ужасный вариант, потому что реализация ValueType.GetHashCode дает много коллизий.

Comment: @Vlad а еще базовая реализация Equals и GetHashCode требует упаковки структуры...

Comment: Не очень хорошо, но малой кровью можно обойтись, если вместо `Pair` воспользоваться стандартным `Tuple<,>`

Comment: или структуру KeyValuePair? Насколько я понимаю, она идентична по функциям тому, что я хотел написать

Comment: @PavelMayorov, хм, про коллизии GetHashCode для ValueType не знал, но не суть. Все зависит от нужд автора вопроса. На небольших объемах - это несущественно. Кстати, вы уверены, что GetHashCode требует упаковки?

Comment: KeyValuePair не переопределяет то, что нужно (хотя оно структура) http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/keyvaluepair.cs,26 , Воспользуйтесь Tuple и не заморачивайтесь

Comment: @Vlad, вот про упаковку подробно: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seteplia/2017/05/17/box-or-not-to-box-that-is-the-question/

Comment: @tym32167 странно. С ней(KeyValuePair) все работало. Хотя мне тоже не ясно почему

Comment: Сработало, потому что она структура.

Comment: @tym32167 понял. Спасибо

Comment: Но почитайте комментарии. Лучше юзать что то, где переопределены equals и gethashcode - у Tuple переопределены, хоть tuple и класс.

Comment: @Vlad ValueType вычисляет хеш-код только по одному полю, первому. Пара значений в качестве ключа подразумевает что одно только первое поле уникальным не является.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Dictionary` для того, чтобы обращаться к элементу по ключу, необходимо сравнивать ключи друг с другом.

Вы должны реализовать операцию сравнения двух объектов класса `Pair<FT, ST>`, например, реализовав интерфейс `IEquatable<Pair<FT, ST>>`, либо, переопределив метод `object.Equals` и `object.GetHashCode`.

Пример реализации `IEquatable<Pair<FT, ST>>`:

```
public class Pair<FT, ST> : IEquatable<Pair<FT, ST>>
{
    private FT x;
    private ST y;

    public Pair()
    { }

    public Pair(FT a, ST b)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }

    public bool Equals(Pair<FT, ST> other)
    {
        return EqualityComparer<FT>.Default.Equals(x, other.x)
            && EqualityComparer<ST>.Default.Equals(y, other.y);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        if (other is Pair<FT, ST>)
            return Equals((Pair<FT, ST>)other);

        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return EqualityComparer<FT>.Default.GetHashCode(x)
             ^ EqualityComparer<ST>.Default.GetHashCode(y);
    }
}
```

Тонкий момент заключается в том, что эта операция сравнения не будет работать, если у типов `FT` и `ST` также нет реализации `IEquatable<T>` или не переопределён метод `object.Equals`.

**UPDATE**

Как здесь ниже справедливо дописали в комментариях, при реализации `IEquality<T>` Microsoft рекомендует также переопределить методы `Equals` и `GetHashCode`, а также операторы `==` и `!=`.

Так что самый *дешёвый* способ, это переопределить методы `Equals` и `GetHashCode`. Добавил изменения в код.

Comment: *"If you implement IEquatable<T>, you should also override the base class implementations of Object.Equals(Object) and GetHashCode so that their behavior is consistent with that of the IEquatable<T>.Equals method."* -- [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `object.GetHashCode` надо в любом случае переопределять.

Comment: Уж если вы Equals через `EqualityComparer` считали - то зачем в `GetHashCode()` внезапный прямой вызов? Ну и XOR - не самый лучший способ комбинирования хеш-кодов; к примеру он дает коллизию при перестановке элементов. ValueTyple использует полиномиальный хеш, лучше и тут использовать нечто похожее.

Comment: Кстати, не могли бы вы перенести свой ответ в основной вопрос? А то там все ответы без кода.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, перенёс, с учётом всех замечаний. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/686671/182162