# Лаконичное переопределение метода Equals для классов с большим числом полей?

Tags: c#

Можно ли как-то лаконично и элегантно его переопределить для классов с большим числом полей?

Решение в лоб- это большой уродский `if` со сравнением полей через `&&`, который еще придется править на каждый чих, если что-то добавляется в класс...

Comment: а что в нем должно быть-то?

Comment: @Grundy, вообще удобно было чем-нибудь на манер рефлексии циклом одноименные поля сравнить, но это медленно...

Comment: И + в том такого подхода в том, что добавляя новое поле, не придется править Equals.

Comment: как вариант: делать класс partial, и выносить часть с equals в файл, который будет например T4 генерировать

Comment: либо вариант с roslyn попробовать

Comment: Может `IValidatable Object` попробовать? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/864831/218063

Comment: Ну и, конечно, в первую очередь читаем это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/719232/218063

Comment: Если ваши типы семантически являются типами-значениями, то их и надо сделать фактически таковыми (`struct`), тогда и вопрос отпадет

Comment: По поводу равенства объектов с одинаковыми значениями свойств: чаю с Новичком никто не желает?

Comment: Можно попробовать кортежи: у них как раз реализовано сравнение по значениям всех свойств.

Answer (score 0):

Сразу оговорюсь, что то решение, которое предложу подойдет лишь с большими оговорками. Правильное направление вам дал @Андрей_NOP в коментариях.

Если по каким-либо причинам вам необходимо сравнить значения public-полей двух классов(интерфейсов), то можно воспользоваться рефлексией:

```
public static class ObjectExtention
{   
    public static bool EqualsByProps<T>(this T source, T target)
    {
        // если один из объектов null - прекратить сравнение 
        // todo : если оба объекта null - ??? 
        if (source == null || target == null) return false;

        return typeof(T)
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
            .All(info =>
            {
                var v1 = info.GetValue(source, null);
                var v2 = info.GetValue(target, null);
                if (v1 == null && v2 == null) return true; 
                return v1?.Equals(v2) == true;
            });
    }
}
```

использовать так:

```
var a = new A{Foo="Foo"};
var b = new A{Foo="Foo"};
var t = a.EqualsByProps(b); // true
```

А теперь минусы:
Если внутри тестируемого экземпляра есть подклассы, то они будут сравниваться через `.Equals()`, и соответственно далее сравнение пойдет не по значению полей.

Чтобы этого избежать можно перегрузить в дочерних классах `.Equals()` и задействовать `.EqualsByProps()`. Но в этом случае получится рекурсивный вызов, а следовательно и риск  циклических ссылок