# Проверка на наличие элемента в ListBox перед добавлением

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть ListBox, код на XAML (убраны ненужные данные):

```
<ListBox Name="listbox1">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="20" Margin="0,1,0,0">
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImagePath}" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name1}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16" Margin="2,-7,0,0" TextOptions.TextHintingMode="Auto" Height="35" MinHeight="35" MaxHeight="35"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Добавляем элементы в список таким образом

```
FFM.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => FFM.listbox1.Items.Add(new ListBoxTemplate() { FullPath = files[i], ImagePath = ImageP, ShortName = text }));
```

Используем Диспетчер, ибо добавляется из другого потока.

Класс ListBoxTemplate:

```
public class ListBoxTemplate
{
    public string Name2{ get; set; }
    public string Name1{ get; set; }
    public BitmapImage ImagePath { get; set; }
}
```

Использую проверку для того, чтобы не добавлять уже существующие, проверяем по Name1:

```
if (!(FFM.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => FFM.listbox1.Items.Contains(new ListBoxTemplate() { Name1= "SomeText"}))))
{
    FFM.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => FFM.listbox1.Items.Add(new ListBoxTemplate() { Name2 = "ExampleText", ImagePath = ImageP, Name1= text }));
}
```

Однако это не помогает, почему и как исправить?

Comment: Что именно не работает? Проверка что уже такой элемент существует?

Comment: В WPF лучше и удобнее работать через привязки (биндинги - как у нас их любят называть). У листбокса есть свойство `ItemsSource` к нему вы можете привязать `ObservableCollection<T>`- коллекция, кот. будет оповещать ListBox о добавлении/удалении элементов. Существует также `Hashset<T>`, кот. позволяет включать в коллекцию только неповторяющиеся элементы.

Comment: Вы делаете неправильно. Добавляйте элементы не вручную, а через ItemsSource.

Comment: Я думаю, что суть вопроса именно в сравнении объектов, поэтому автору нужно почитать это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/460/218063 Либо проверять не через `.Contains()`, а с помощью `.Any(x => x.Name1 == text)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот код (демонстрационный пример), который решает вашу проблему конкретно по заданному вопросу.

То что лучше добавлять элементы с помощью `ObservableCollection<T>` и как-то по другому определять содержит ли коллекция элемент это другой вопрос. Более оптимальные способы автор, думаю, сможет придумать/нагуглить.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace WpfApp2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string newName = "Test1";
            var newItem = new ListBoxTemplate() { Name2 = "ExampleText", ImagePath = new BitmapImage(), Name1 = newName };

            // Task только для демострации, а так смысла тут его использовать нет
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                if (!ContainsItem(newName))
                {
                    AddItem(newItem);
                }
            });

        }

        private void AddItem(ListBoxTemplate newItem)
        {
            if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action<ListBoxTemplate>(AddItem), newItem);
            }
            else
            {
                listbox1.Items.Add(newItem);
            }
        }

        private bool ContainsItem(string nameOfItem)
        {
            if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                return (bool)Dispatcher.Invoke(new Func<string, bool>(ContainsItem), nameOfItem);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var listBoxItem in listbox1.Items)
                {
                    var item = (ListBoxTemplate)listBoxItem;
                    if (item.Name1 == nameOfItem)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public class ListBoxTemplate
    {
        public string Name2 { get; set; }
        public string Name1 { get; set; }
        public BitmapImage ImagePath { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно и так. Как говорится: используй то, что есть под рукой и не ищи другое.