# Как сравнить BackgroundImage у PictureBox с картинкой в Resourse?

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

```
pictureBox_HidePass.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.hide;
        bool a = pictureBox_HidePass.BackgroundImage == Properties.Resources.hide;
```

Почему выдает false. Или как то по другому нужно сравнивать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Чем отличаются оператор == и вызов метода object.Equals в C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/460/%d0%a7%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-object-equals-%d0%b2-c)

Comment: Объекты следует сравнивать _хотя бы_ при помощи метода `Equals`, а не переопределённого оператора сравнения `==`

Comment: @Nowhere Man
То есть вот так: pictureBox_HidePass.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.hide;
            bool a = pictureBox_HidePass.BackgroundImage.Equals(Properties.Resources.hide); Но и так false

Comment: Если дело дошло до сравнения картинок, значит в логике проекта явно что-то пошло не так. Картинки сравниваются по ссылкам, а не по содержимому, то есть `true` будет только если картинку сравнить саму с собой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите код, сгенерированный для класса `Properties.Resources`. В свойстве `hide` будет что-то вроде:

```
internal static System.Drawing.Bitmap hide {
    get {
        object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("hide", resourceCulture);
        return ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)(obj));
    }
}
```

То есть при **каждом** обращении к этому свойству создаётся **новый** объект `Bitmap`. Соответственно, даже их ссылки не равны.

---

Сделайте поле:

```
private readonly Bitmap _hide;
```

Задайте ему значение из ресурсов

```
_hide = Properties.Resources.hide;
```

Далее везде используйте это поле:

```
pictureBox_HidePass.BackgroundImage = _hide;
```

```
bool a = pictureBox_HidePass.BackgroundImage == _hide;
```